# vue.reactive is not a function in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

when I create this error appear I'm not sure hot fix it.
I ready build a web app and then I just create a store.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2C4f.png)

`/store/index.js`

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    title: "My custom title"
  },
  mutations: {},
  modules: {},
  actions: {}
});
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";
import router from "./router/routes";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

Vue.component("Navbar", Navbar);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Check if your packages versions are compatible with each other. Don't want to be guessing but looks like you have to new Vuex for Vue 2.

Comment: I have "vuex": "4.0.2" in package.json

Comment: I just fix the issues i was having. Thank You

Comment: Cool, can I make a few points out of this. Can you mark my answer as correct one?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your packages versions are compatible with each other. Don't want to be guessing but looks like you have too new Vuex for Vue 2.

Try installing Vuex in version 3.

Comment: Can confirm that this is in fact the issue. Was Initially using Vuex 4, rolling back to v3.6.2 did the trick.

Comment: I have the same error, but as I revert the repository to the original version it is still there. I dont understand it. Compilation is successfull but browser throws me this. It is a Nuxt project.